# Работает ли виртуализация если из шаблона ListView убрать ScrollViewer чтобы не мешать ScrollViewer'у выше по дереву?

Tags: c#, wpf, виртуализация

Обычно у `ListView` такой шаблон:

```
<Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness=" 
     {TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

И если к примеру `TabControl`'у добавить `ScrollViewer` для всех `TabItem`, то потом внутри проблемы со списками, а именно происходит перехват дочерними `ScrollViewer`'ами.

Меня интересует, сохранится ли виртуализация, которая, как мне кажется, работает именно со `ScrollViewer` из шаблона, будет ли она работать с `ScrollViewer`'ом выше?

Comment: Так это можно же проверить в Live Tree (или как оно там называется, пару лет уже с wpf дела не имел), если есть виртуализация, то в визуальном дереве будет минимальное количество элементов, по числу на экране, в противном — будет столько сколько элементов в VM